# How is this belief muttar?

Tags: avodah-zarah, heresy, zohar

A friend of mine mentioned yesterday during our se'udah with the way in which the Zohar comments on a particular mitzvah lo ta'ase. In Devarim 16, Hashem commands us not to erect an asherah by the mizbe'ach. The Zohar apparently tries to whitewash this by explaining it as a separation between Hashem and the Shechinah. However, in the times of Bayit Rishon, Asherah was viewed by idolaters as a consort for Hashem.

When I subsequently queried him on the makor, he said that he believes that the citation is 1:49a.

Considering that the Zohar effectively rehashes this ancient avodah zarah, how can this belief (and by extension, the Zohar) be muttar?

Comment: Do you mean a commandment to *not* separate male and female aspects?

Comment: @paquda, the belief that the Asherah represents the female aspect of Hashem is a rehash of a very old belief that hashem was not אחד and that Asherah is his consort. See Patai's book on the subject, although he contends that this inyan was more mainstream than ע”ז should ever be.

Comment: I'm just asking about your sentence "my friend mentioned that the Zohar views this as a commandment to separate male and female aspects of Hashem"--it seems more likely the zohar would view it as a commandment to **not** separate.

Comment: @paquda, I was trying to find a better turn of phrase, but nothing came to mind.

Comment: @paquda, is that better?

Comment: This seems like it just comes down to whether you accept the Zohar or nor. If you do, then this is acceptable by definition. If not, then this is one more reason to reject it. I think that a better way to ask the question would be whether this is ever invoked as a proof against the Zohar, and what the response to the claim was.

Comment: Even after the edit, I don't get exactly what the Zohar says, and how it related to the ancient a"z of asherah.

Comment: @mevaqesh, in Kehillas Ashkenaz, there's a cherem against the Zohar, so I can't look it up inside to get a better way of explaining. Regardless, as I commented to Paquda, Patai's book is all about syncretic avodah zarah in the times of Bayit Rishon and the pantheon which was developed, making Asherah Hashem's consort.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt How is this question not in violation of that Cherem? Because you didn't read the exact words yourself?

Comment: Can you please summarize the point which disturbed you.  1, 49 is a page?  a chapter?

Comment: If you included the explanation on male and female principles mentioned in your comments the question will be clarified

Comment: @DoubleAA,  I did not look inside the Zohar, in accordance with Rabbanei Ashkenaz. There are books which discuss the Zohar by these same rabbanim which are permissible to us though. See R' Rallis Wiesenthal, who discusses the Zohar and why we do not add passages from it into the siddur.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a concept that some of God's  traits are "feminine" and that He has both masculine and feminine aspects but that is different from saying that there is a separate god that is God's wife.

Saying that God can defeat armies is not the same as believing in Mars, god of war.

Comment: I maintain that this would be better served as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it , it does not address the ע”ז being forbidden and and instead merely repeats claims which are fairly common-knowledge. The way this answer attempts to disprove the OP is insufficient IMO to really be of any great quality

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt If you ask a question whose answer is common knowledge, that's what you should expect in the answers.

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe something better thought out? I would also expect that over the years, supporters of the Zohar would have come up with all sorts of arguments against questions like mine, presumably based in more grounded mekorot.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt This answer is thought out. It shows the fallacy you're making. No need for fancy mekorot to see your fallacy.

Comment: I am saying that your equation of the zohars belief in a multifaceted god with A.z's belief in multiple gods is spurious.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, to equate the Asherah to the feminine aspects of Hashem is a"z! Asherah is a foreign deity of Cana'ani origin!

Comment: But the zohar doesn't equate multifacetedness with ashera.